# Configuring the uploadConfig for Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Is there documentation about that explains how to configure the upload config in YUI. I am trying to upload temporarily into a folder in a user's home space so I don't need all siteId that's specified in the examples I have been reading about so far.

I'd like to configure the object with the details I need to pass.

Comment: Could you please tell which examples you are referring and bit more detail will give more clarity on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for in [Share Client Side API](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-4.0.d/symbols/Alfresco.FileUpload.html) by accident.
Where the upload path can be specified.

```
     var multiUploadConfig =
     {
        destination : this.options.tempfolder,
        containerId: "consultation",
        filter: [],

        mode: this.fileUpload.MODE_MULTI_UPLOAD,
        thumbnails: "doclib",
        onFileUploadComplete:
        {
           fn: this.onFileUploadComplete,
           scope: this
        }
     };
```